# How can I efficiently find the standard deviation of a single pixel's value across time? (from video feed)

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

(Just a note, my app takes a video feed at 1920x1080@60fps, and the processing and calculations are done post-recording. The videos recorded are all less than ~6 seconds.)

I am currently developing an image processing algorithm to run on an android device and need to calculate the standard deviation (and mean) of a single pixel's value across time. In other words, I want to be able to determine what the standard deviation for an arbitrary pixel at coordinate (x, y) is across z seconds/frames.
I use VideoCapture to read the video feed frame by frame.

OpenCV does not seem to provide functions for processing across the time axis, so I have had to implement my own processing functions. Currently, my algorithm makes use of an incremental computation method (more on it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102978/incremental-computation-of-standard-deviation) to calculate stdev, but it runs very slowly on a mobile device. I use this iterative method because I originally tried to organize each pixel's data into separate vectors/lists to then perform mean and stdev calculations on, but I ran out of memory given the video resolution, frame rate, and video duration.

```
// Define window boundaries
int startFrame = i * frameRate + temporalSizeRBF;
int endFrame = (i + 1) * frameRate + temporalSizeRBF - 1;
// Calculating Mean and STD for current window
// First frame (frame 0)
vc.read(frame);
// Extract only red channel
Core.extractChannel(frame, redMat, 2);
redMat.convertTo(mean, CvType.CV_64FC1, 1/255.0);
stdev = Mat.zeros(frameHeight, frameWidth, CvType.CV_64FC1);
// Rest of the frames [1:frameRate)
for (int j = startFrame + 1; j <= endFrame; j++) {
    double n = j - startFrame + 1;
    Log.d(TAG, "Current Frame: " + n);
    vc.read(frame);
    Core.extractChannel(frame, redMat, 2);
    redMat.convertTo(convRedMat, CvType.CV_64FC1, 1/255.0);
    // Per row
    for (int x = 0; x < frame.rows(); x++) {
        // Per col
        for (int y = 0; y < frame.cols(); y++) {
            double newStd = (stdev.get(x, y)[0] * ((n - 2) / (n - 1))) + ((1 / n) * Math.pow(convRedMat.get(x, y)[0] - mean.get(x, y)[0], 2));
            double newMean =  (convRedMat.get(x, y)[0] + (n - 1) * mean.get(x, y)[0]) / n;
            stdev.put(x, y, newStd);
            mean.put(x, y, newMean);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to extract and process the **entire** red channel, yet your description says you just want the standard deviation of a **single** pixel?

Comment: @MarkSetchell My bad, that was unclear. I meant to say I want to calculate the standard deviation for each individual pixel across time, for all pixels in the red channel.

Comment: Note that `.get(x, y)` is very slow. To do something with each pixel you should use the iterators that `cv::Mat` provides, or use raw pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the lack of proper 3+ dimensional Matrices on OpenCV Java (at least for OCV 3.4), I decided to proceed and refine the iterative method of calculating Stdev. Instead of doing pixel by pixel traversals, I used the array operations that OpenCV provides in its Core library (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html).

Here is my solution.

```
int startFrame = i * fps + offset;
int endFrame = (i + 1) * fps + offset - 1;
// Calculating STD for current window
// First frame (frame 0)
frame = frames.get(startFrame);
Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, bgr, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420);
// Extract only red channel
Core.extractChannel(bgr, redMat, 2);
redMat.convertTo(mean, CvType.CV_32FC1, 1/255.0);
var = Mat.zeros((int) frameSize.height, (int) frameSize.width, CvType.CV_32FC1);
// Rest of the frames [1:frameRate)
for (int j = startFrame + 1; j <= endFrame; j++) {
    double n = j - startFrame + 1;
    Log.d(TAG, "Current Frame: " + n);
    frame = frames.get(j);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, bgr, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420);
    Core.extractChannel(bgr, redMat, 2);
    redMat.convertTo(convRedMat, CvType.CV_32FC1, 1/255.0);
    // Calculate the iterative variance and mean for this frame
    // Var(n) = (n-2)/(n-1)*var(n-1) + 1/n*(X(n) - Mean(n-1))^2
    Core.multiply(var, new Scalar((n-2)/(n-1)), var); // (n-2)/(n-1)*var(n-1)
    Core.subtract(convRedMat, mean, temp1); // (X(n) - Mean(n-1))
    Core.multiply(temp1, temp1, temp2); // (X(n) - Mean(n-1))^2
    Core.multiply(temp2, new Scalar(1/n), temp2); // 1/n*(X(n) - Mean(n-1))^2
    Core.add(var, temp2, var); // (n-2)/(n-1)*var(n-1) + 1/n*(X(n) - Mean(n-1))^2
    // Mean(n) = 1/n*(X(n) + (n-1)*Mean(n-1))
    Core.multiply(mean, new Scalar(n-1), temp1); // (n-1)*Mean(n-1)
    Core.add(convRedMat, temp1, temp2); // X(n) - (n-1)*Mean(n-1)
    Core.multiply(temp2, new Scalar(1/n), mean);
}
```

At the end of this we then square root the values of the var matrix to find the standard deviation of each pixel.

Using the OpenCV matrix operations significantly decreased runtime for the algorithm.

**Note** - these are the CvTypes of the matrices used:

- bgr - **8UC3**
- redMat - **8UC1**
- mean, stdev, convRedMat, temp1, temp2 - **32FC1**